# Use Kendo UI Flip Effects / Combined Effects for multiple items on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I need to use kendo ui to display between 6-60 items. Each using the flip effect here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/fx/combined

The products will be loaded from the database with the unique id like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 product-container">
    <div id="productID1" class="productID">
        <div class="product">
            <div id="product-back1" class="product-desc">
                <p>BACK</p>
            </div>
            <div id="product-front1" class="product-image">
                <p>FRONT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 product-container">
    <div id="productID2" class="productID">
        <div class="product">
            <div id="product-back2" class="product-desc">
                <p>BACK</p>
            </div>

            <div id="product-front2" class="product-image">
                <p>FRONT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 product-container">
    <div id="productID3" class="productID">
        <div class="product">
            <div id="product-back3" class="product-desc">
                <p>BACK</p>
            </div>
            <div id="product-front3" class="product-image">
                <p>FRONT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I need multiple panels on the page how can I make each "front"  and "back" click unique.

```
   var el = kendo.fx($('div[id^=productID]')),
    flip = el.flip("horizontal", $('div[id^=product-front]'), $('div[id^=product-back]')),
    zoom = el.zoomIn().startValue(1).endValue(1);

flip.add(zoom).duration(200);

$('div[id^=product-front]').click(function () {
    flip.stop().play();
});

$('div[id^=product-back]').click(function () {
    flip.stop().reverse();
});
```

I've tried loading each item into an array but have not found a good way to assure the correct item will be flipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every `div[id^=product-front]` is a child of `div[id^=productID]`, you can find the children of that and use it.

replace `flip.stop().play();` with

```
kendo.fx($(this)).flip("horizontal", $(this).children()[0], $(this).children()[1]).stop().play();
```

Comment: In the $('div[id^=product-front]').click(function () {
    flip.stop().play();
}); Function?  or the call at the top  var el = kendo.fx($('div[id^=productID]')),
    flip = el.flip("horizontal", $('div[id^=product-front]'), $('div[id^=product-back]')),
    zoom = el.zoomIn().startValue(1).endValue(1); neither seems to flip the panel.

Comment: it's just pseudo code. I intended for this code to be in the function, but the logic is that you should use the children of the parent selector to assure the correct item will be flipped.

Comment: I have the flip working from the front to back unfortunately the reverse, doesn't work, when called the same way kendo.fx($(this)).flip("horizontal", $(this).children()[1], $(this).children()[0]).stop().reverse();

Comment: My mistake I failed to move the "productID" to the parent positon, it was one level up.  Thanks for your help!